# How to rewrite window.prompt(title) with textarea in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to provide terminal-like way of input for the user using `textarea`  instead of `window.prompt(title)`.

my code is:

```
     var Module = {
         waitingForEnter: false, // for user_input function

         ...

         user_input: (function() {
            var element = document.getElementById('output'); // textarea control
            if (element) element.value = ''; // clear browser cache

            return function() {
                // enable for user typing
                element.readOnly = false;
                Module.waitingForEnter = true;
                var initialLength = element.value.length;

                element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
                element.focus(); // set caret blinking

                while (Module.waitingForEnter) {}; // problem: hangs here and does not allow user to type !

                // disable for typing and return what the user typed
                element.readOnly = true;
                return element.value.substr(initialLength, element.value.length-1); // ignore last \n
            };
        })(),

        ...
```

The problem is that it hangs and i believe it's because of `while` loop. How can i fix it? Also how can i add listener to `textarea` for Enter to be typed programmatically and set `Module.waitingForEnter = false`?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the browser will never get past this line:
`while (Module.waitingForEnter) {}`

What you need to do is work with events, more specifically key events. These allow you to keep track of the user input.

For example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('output');
element.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if ((event.keyCode || event.which) === 13) {  //  enter key
        //  assuming the textarea contains only the user input
        handleUserInput(this.value);
        //  clear the user input
        this.value = '';
    }
});
```

I picked `keypress` as this is the most intuitive one, the following events can be observed (in order of triggering):

- `keydown` > a key went down
- `keyup` > a key went up
- `keypress` > a key went down and up again

If you're trying to emulate a terminal or something, I think `keypress` will suffice.

Comment: probably you're right, but how does `window.prompt` work? It also waits for the user input and does blocking without all events stopped from being handled.

Comment: `window.prompt` is a native control, handled by the browser. It actually stops the current code execution and continues once one of the buttons is clicked. Under the hood it will most likely also be implemented using an event mechanism, but on OS level. As you don't have the luxury of actually pausing javascript execution, you cannot implement it the same way. There simply is no good synchronous way of handling interaction, which - by design - is asynchronous.

Comment: probably you're right but i hope to find any `processEvents` method ... like in old good Delphi

Comment: You won't. That is the most honest answer I can give you. You simple need to come to terms with the fact that in 'good old Delphi' you have control on OS level, while in a browser you (thankfully) don't have that kind of access. Embrace the event-driven nature of javascript and you'll be good ;-), maybe a little fiddle helps you setting your mind to the simplicity of events: https://jsfiddle.net/rknLzrkz/1/. From my perspective, events tend to reduce the amount of code needed, then again, I can see how this takes some time to get used to.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you don't need `while` loop in such case. Consider my solution that shown bellow:

```
var Module = {
         waitingForEnter: false, // for user_input function

         inputEl: document.getElementById('output'), // textarea control

         user_input: (function() {
            if (this.inputEl) this.inputEl.value = ''; // clear browser cache

            return function(e) {
                var initialLength = e.target.value.length;
                e.target.scrollTop = e.target.scrollHeight; // focus on bottom
                e.target.focus(); // set caret blinking

                return e.target.value.substr(initialLength, e.target.value.length-1); // ignore last \n
            };
        })(),

        allow_input: function(){
              setTimeout(function(){
                    // enable for user typing
                    Module.inputEl.readOnly = false;
                    Module.waitingForEnter = true;
               }, 5000);
        },

        block_input: function(e){
            // disable for typing and return what the user typed
            e.target.readOnly = true;
            this.waitingForEnter = false;

            this.allow_input(); // just for example : allow user input in defered manner
        },

        init: function(){
            this.inputEl.addEventListener('input', this.user_input.bind(this));
            this.inputEl.addEventListener('change', this.block_input.bind(this));
        }
};


Module.init();
```

One of thing that remains to you is to decide at which moment you will allow user to resume input (revise my `setTimeout` stub with some other way)
https://jsfiddle.net/56dv6tr3/

Comment: not sure i understand your solution. First, i need to have function that waits for user input and returns it (just like `window.promt()`). No callback are allowed - i should be able to run it like `var input = readInput()` and not `readInput(callbackFunc)`. Will i be able to do it with your `user_input ` impl?

Comment: if there is any function like 'processEvents' it would be solved just like `while(!condition) { processEvents(); }`

Comment: @4ntoine, consider that `window.prompt` acts like popup in blocking manner, but `textarea` is just one of DOM elements, and you are able to get an updated value from `textarea` only via handling such events as `input`, `change`, `paste` etc.

Comment: yes, i understands that clearly. my point is that window.prompt() works in the way i need so somehow it should be possible to do it with textarea too. but all current suggestions do not suit because they don't provide synchronous way of invocation. in the means of thread/blocking typing in alert input is exactly the same as typing in textarea.

Comment: probably, you should look the way of 'custom' prompt window or JQuery dialog plugin http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/